# Comparing data in QGIS

Tags: vector, comparison, buffer, raster, qgis

Good day

I have a GIS map with two layers:

1. landcover (raster dataset)
2. Points (vector dataset)

I want to see what is the most common landcover within a 2km radius of each point.

I tried the "clip raster by mask layer" function, but that doesn't tell me which landcover is the most common. I was wondering if someone could help?

Kind regards